# NgModule not found after update on Angular 5

Tags: angular

I tried to update my app to Angular 5. A few bugs later, I now have one that I can't fix.

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModuleShared'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

I checked my AppModuleShared and don't found an error.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

import { StoreModule } from './store/store.module';
import { LandingPageModule } from './components/landingpage/landingpage.module';

//import { RegisterComponent } from './components/auth/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/auth/login/login.component';
import { HeaderLoginComponent } from './components/auth/headerlogin/headerlogin.component';

import { MessageListComponent } from './components/messagelist/messagelist.component';

import { AuthModule } from './components/auth/auth.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        HeaderLoginComponent,
        MessageListComponent


    ],
    providers: [

    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpClient,
        FormsModule,
        StoreModule,
        LandingPageModule,
        AuthModule,
        HttpClient,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([

            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModuleShared {
    constructor(
    ) {
    }

}
```

Who knows what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be importing HttpClient. That's imported directly inside of your components. The imports section is for modules only. The HttpClientModule should be the only one imported inside of NgModule imports. (Also why do you have it imported twice?) You have:

```
import: [
  HttpClient,

  ...
  HttpClient,
  HttpModule

]
```

but it should be:

```
import: [
  ...
  HttpClientModule
]
```

and in components:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Remove the `HtttpClient` from the import

2) Add it to the constructor: `constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

It's a dependency of the HttpClientModule [HttpClientModule official docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientModule)

Comment: Why the negative?